# What are the solution for setText

Tags: android, xml

How can I solve this problem?

This error shows up when ('name.setText(Name)').
What are the suggestions to solve this problem?

I already tried another solution but it still occurs.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

```
public class ReportFragment extends Fragment {

TextView name,roomNo,college,matNo,phoneNo;
private static final String TAG = "ReportFragment";
private FirebaseFirestore db =  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private String Name,Mat,Col,Room,Phone;
private CollectionReference eventsRef = db.collection("EventsQR");
private EventsRecycleViewAdapter adapter;
protected FragmentActivity myContext;
private Context context;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser user;

public ReportFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Activity){
        this.myContext = (FragmentActivity) context;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report,container,false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.viewRecycleview_id);

    name =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    matNo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.matNo);
    college =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.college);
    roomNo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.roomNo);
    phoneNo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);


    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(myContext));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



    return view;
}

@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();
    String username = user.getEmail();


    db.collection("users")
            .whereEqualTo("email", username)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            Name = document.getString("name");
                            Mat = document.getString("Matrix No");
                            Col = document.getString("College");
                            Room = document.getString("Room No");
                            Phone = document.getString("phone");
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: name"+Name+Mat+Col+Room+Phone);


                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }


            });

    name.setText(Name);
    matNo.setText(Mat);
    college.setText(Col);
    roomNo.setText(Room);
    phoneNo.setText(Phone);


    Query query = eventsRef;

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<QrDetails> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<QrDetails>()
            .setQuery(query,QrDetails.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new EventsRecycleViewAdapter(options, myContext);
}
```

This is the xml file:

```xml
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Name : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Matrix No : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/matNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Matrix No" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="College : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/college"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="College" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Room No : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roomNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Room No" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Phone No : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Phone No" />
```

Comment: paste full java code

Comment: Init your view with view.findViewbyid() inside onViewCreated() method

Comment: Well, why is 'name'  null?

Comment: @Rasel done editing

Comment: put you name =(TextView)myContext.findViewById(R.id.name); like code in onCreateView and inflate from view. like: name =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);

Comment: is the posted xml fragment_report.xml?

Comment: @Rasel yes. it is on fragment_report

Comment: @Rasel the error from log is at name.setText(Name);

Answer (score 0):

Post this in OnViewCreated.

```
    name =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    matNo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.matNo);
    college =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.college);
    roomNo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.roomNo);
    phoneNo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);
```

Init your view after OnCreateView() call or inside onViewCreated().
in onCreate, it will not get initialized.

Comment: it still have the same error.The error is at                                                                   
        name.setText(Name);

Answer (score 0):

Put your `onCreate` method code into `onActivityCreated` method and initilize your views in `onCreateView` and call `setText` on your text views inside `onComplete` method like so:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report,container,false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.viewRecycleview_id);
    name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    matNo = view.findViewById(R.id.matNo);
    college = view.findViewById(R.id.college);
    roomNo = view.findViewById(R.id.roomNo);
    phoneNo = view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(myContext));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();
    String username = user.getEmail();


    db.collection("users")
            .whereEqualTo("email", username)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            Name = document.getString("name");
                            Mat = document.getString("Matrix No");
                            Col = document.getString("College");
                            Room = document.getString("Room No");
                            Phone = document.getString("phone");
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: name"+Name+Mat+Col+Room+Phone);

                            name.setText(Name);
                            matNo.setText(Mat);
                            college.setText(Col);
                            roomNo.setText(Room);
                            phoneNo.setText(Phone);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }

            });



    Query query = eventsRef;

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<QrDetails> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<QrDetails>()
            .setQuery(query,QrDetails.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new EventsRecycleViewAdapter(options, myContext);
}
```

Comment: There are no output to display

Comment: there are no output for that id. it is null with no data

Comment: Are you sure db onComplete method initializes your variables correctly? @MuhamadQiwamuddin

Comment: yes im sure. In log, The Log.d(Tag,....) show all the data. but at name.setText(Name); is the problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can `initialize` your `views` inside `onCreateView` like `recylerview`

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report,container,false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.viewRecycleview_id);

    // here you should initialize your views
    name =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    matNo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.matNo);
    college =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.college);
    roomNo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.roomNo);
    phoneNo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(myContext));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Already tryied but the problem is at name.setText(Name); Its is from log